# LDAP or VBscript to list all real users in AD

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

Please can you help me with a LDAP query or VBscript to list all current users; real, flesh and blood people so it must exclude service accounts, administrator accounts and shared mailboxes.

If you can help with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know (in your script) whether an account is a "flesh-and-blood" account or a service account?? What attribute can you check to make that decision?? I'm not aware of any "real user" flag in AD - but maybe you can base your decision on something that your company is using.

Once you know that fact, then you should be able to find something on Richard Mueller's [website](http://www.rlmueller.net/products.htm) - he has tons of examples for VBScript and Active Directory - [this page here](http://www.rlmueller.net/freecode6.htm) has a number of premade VBScripts to handle things like creating a list of users and many others. Adapt these for your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for the links to Richard Mueller's website, they were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, anyway... to get "flesh-and-blood" :) account, try this:

**Users** who are **persons** AND company and email address cannot be blank AND the manager field cannot be blank:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(company=*)(mail=*)(|(manager=*)))
```

... or this to:

**Users** who are **persons** AND company and email address cannot be blank AND the manager field cannot be blank unless the user’s name is Mr. Brown:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(company=*)(mail=*)(|(manager=*)(name=Mr. Brown)))
```

Note: The operation `(|(manager=*)(name=Mr. Brown))` means that either `manager=* or name=Mr. Brown` must be true.

Source: https://help.mypurecloud.com/articles/create-ldap-query/